# Create a new rails application inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I have created a new rails app. Inside the controller I have used a shell cmd to create a new rails app,

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def index
    exec "rails new testing -d postgresql"
  end

  def list
  end
end
```

I get the following error.
 Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first. Type 'rails' for help.

I understand that its impossible to create a new rails application inisde another application.

Is there any function to specify the storage location in exec command?
or something like this  exec "[directory location] rails new testing -d postgresql"..?

Comment: Do not use `exec`! It replaces the current process. Use `system`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the path to the `rails new` command:

```
system "rails new /target/folder/testing -d postgresql"
```

Or `cd` to the target folder and then run `rails new`. Like this:

```
system "cd /target/folder && rails new testing -d postgresql"
```

Comment: I tried exec "cd /c/Users/username && rails new testing123 -d postgresql"    but i get an error: The system cannot find path specified..    But I cross checked the target path in command prompt, the path exists..   could you please point my mistake.?

Comment: If it says it does not exist it does not exist. Are you using Windows? Do you mean `c:\Users` instead of `/c/Users`? Did you try my other suggestion?

Comment: tried        system "cd ~ && rails new testing2 -d postgresql"  The system cannot find the specified path..  still no fruit..

Comment: Maybe that syntax doesn't work on Windows. Just try my other suggestion: `system "rails new c:\Users\username\testing2 -d postgresql"`.

Comment: Tried system "rails new C:\testin -d postgresql"  and also  system "cd C:\ && rails new testin -d postgresql"   and also    and executed through windows terminal this time...  still shows:-  system cannot find the specified path..  Have you tried this in your machine Mischa..?

Comment: I am using a Mac, so it's completely different, but I tried it in irb and it works. Sorry it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late but having wanted to do something similar, here is what worked for me:

1. `cd ~/Projects; rails new #{@app.name}` (With the backticks around it)- This one executed "silently". No output was shown and the app hanged while `rails new` ran
2. `system "cd ~/Projects; rails new #{@app.name}"` - This showed the output on the console i.e. the generated files were shown along with the `bundle install` and the app hanged meanwhile
3. `exec "cd ~/Projects; rails new #{@app.name}"` - This shut down the server and showed the output for `rails new` and `bundle install`

I wanted to create an app from within another app. In your case, I suppose you could do:
`exec "cd folder_name; rails new testing -d postgresql"`.
I would suggest you use either of the first two options as `exec` shuts down the server and brings your app to a halt.